# regular expression to extract values from a string

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a string in this format:

```
 Index  val1    val2  val3 val4
" 09     46.6   33.4  11   33.8  "
```

I have to extract the values val1 to val4. It can be done by this regex:

```
(?<index>\d{2})\s+(?<val1>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val2>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val3>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)\s+(?<val4>(\d+\.?\d+)|\w+)
```

Now the problem I am facing is that any one of the values in the string can be blank as well. And in that case if fails. So how do I extract, for example, values from this:

```
 Index  val1    val2  val3 val4
" 09     46.6         11   33.8  "
```

Note that any or all values can be blank, except the index value. The header row is provided in the file.
Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify which flavor of regex / tool you want to use as a tag as there is too much variation between tools.

Comment: Perl Compatible Regular Expressions(PCRE)

Comment: if there will be blank spot, how do You create it with a multiple space or maybe a tab \t?

Comment: @akfaz what is see is that the blank spot is either 3 or 4 spaces wide

Answer (score 0):

suppose text.txt has your data

```
:~$ awk '{print $0}' text.txt | tr -d \" > out
:~$ awk '{ print substr($0, index($0,$2))}' out
```

this should give you the desired output, I am new to awk so didnt know how to do it in one line

In the first line I am deleting the `"` so that I can directly compare the values without `"`

Answer (score 0):

what comes to my mind is that solution(it should work for I blank space):

```
(\b\d+[.]?\d\b)|(\s{6})
```

however I'm so satisfied with it, because You need to know the predefined distance in case of the blank space

http://regex101.com/r/jS5aL0

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to use regular expressions for your problem when it can be solved using simple string functions: Extract substrings and trim all whitespace - the result should be either a decimal number or an empty string.

Example in Python

```
index = line[0:3].strip()
val1 = line[3:12].strip()
val2 = line[12:19].strip()
val3 = line[19:23].strip()
val4 = line[23:30].strip()
```

Comment: You can't assume the length of the individual values and the position where they start.

Comment: How does the format work? How do you know 11 is under val2 and not val3? If its a question of hardcoding, you could just do a first pass to determine those widths.

Comment: @wanderer: If you can't assume the length of the individual values, then there is no way to distinguish between val1, val2, val3, or val4 being blank in your example.

Comment: @CiroSantilli the minimum width between numbers is 3 whites spaces. It could be more if the next number is blank

Comment: @nd. well that is the problem

Comment: @wanderer - yes, but this is not (yet) a regex problem. The format is underspecified and ambiguous. You can either guess which val is empty or improve the format specification.

Comment: @nd. well I am reading some file provided to me by someone and that is the issue. The format is like that.

Comment: To me the problem is: what is the column separator? Exactly 3 spaces? If there can be more than 3 spaces, how do you know how how many empty columns are there if there are 2 or 3 consecutive empty columns?

Comment: @CiroSantilli I get what you are saying and is what was troubling me..the file has the blank spot which is either 3 or 4 spaces wide..The value should be roughly under the heading above, if that helps